# .Net HttpWebRequest ClientCertificates not sent to API

Tags: .net, ssl, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to call an API over HTTPS. The API expects a client certificate to be sent, which it will then validate. The API doesn't return some list of accepted CAs or so (like in a standard web server TLS flow), it just expects a certificate to validate.

On the client machine, where my app runs, the client certificate is installed in the local machine\personal store (where it also looks ok by checking it in `certlm.msc`). I'm able to get the certificate from the store and add it to my `HttpWebRequest` like so `request.ClientCertificates.Add(cert)`. Inspecting the certificate in the app code at runtime it has a private key (`HasPrivateKey` is `true` and the `PrivateKey` property contains data). For testing purposes I granted `everyone` read access to the certificate to be sure they private key can be retrieved with the certificate from the app, seems to work.

However, the API complains no certificate was sent. Checking the request with Wireshark shows a `TLSv1.2` handshake of type `Certificate`, however `Certificate Length: 0`. So indeed the certificate is not sent up.

Using Postman to call the exact same API with the exact same certificate (from a file, as Postman needs a file, the file being the `.pfx` from which the certificate was imported in the machine\personal store) DOES send the certificate. Wireshark shows `Certificate Length: 770` and I'm able to view the certificate details.

So it seems that for some reason, even though I attach the certificate to the `HttpWebRequest.ClientCertificates` it doesn't get sent up from app code. There's no exception, it just won't get sent.

To recap:

- `HttpWebRequest.ClientCertificates` contains a certificate retrieved from the machine\personal store
- the certificate has a private key
- the certificate (in `certlm.msc`) looks good (trusted CA etc)
- the certificate doesn't get set up to the API
- however the same certificate *does* get set up when calling the API from postman
- the app is a .Net 4.6.1 wpf app

Any ideas what I'm missing? Thanks!

(later edit)

I debugged the `SecureChannel` class in the framework which is the one handling the sending of certificates and found some worrying stuff. First, some comments:

```
Here is how we work:
                case 0: Cert Selection delegate is present
                        Alwasys use its result as the client cert answer.
                        Try to use cached credential handle whenever feasible.
                        Do not use cached anonymous creds if the delegate has returned null
                        and the collection is not empty (allow responding with the cert later).

                case 1: Certs collection is empty
                        Always use the same statically acquired anonymous SSL Credential

                case 2: Before our Connection with the Server
                        If we have a cached credential handle keyed by first X509Certificate
                        **content** in the passed collection, then we use that cached
                        credential and hoping to restart a session.

                        Otherwise create a new anonymous (allow responding with the cert later).

                case 3: After our Connection with the Server (ie during handshake or re-handshake)
                        The server has requested that we send it a Certificate then
                        we Enumerate a list of server sent Issuers trying to match against
                        our list of Certificates, the first match is sent to the server.

                        Once we got a cert we again try to match cached credential handle if possible.
                        This will not restart a session but helps miminizing the number of handles we create.
```

Debugging the code, the comments seem to hold:

- first it checks for the cert selection delegate: there is none and the certificates collection contains my certificate so it moves on to step 2
- here it takes my certificate, checks for a valid private key, is successful, then comes a new comment

```
// (see VsWhidbey#363953) For some (probably good) reason IIS does not renegotiate a restarted session if client cert is needed.
                    // So we don't want to reuse **anonymous** cached credential for a new SSL connection if the client has passed some certificate.
                    // The following block happens if client did specify a certificate but no cached creds were found in the cache
                    // Since we don't restart a session the server side can still challenge for a client cert.
```

... after which this code...

```
   if ((object)clientCertificate != (object)selectedCert)
                        selectedCert.Reset();
                    guessedThumbPrint = null;
                    selectedCert = null;
                    clientCertificate = null;
```

So basically it will `null` the reference to the certificate I passed in. If I understand it correctly this is to work around some IIS issue and it means that it expects the server to send back a list of issuers to filter the certificates by (which would be case 3 from the comment), which is indeed what I see in the code. Only if this list of issuers comes down from the server will the code go through the client certificates and filter them by the issuers and then send the matching one(s) up.

Now I'm left wondering: is it only possible to send client certificates if the server asks for a list of issuers? Because in my case the API I'm calling does not do that, it simply expects a certificate. I hope I'm wrong and someone can shed light on this.

**(even later edit)**

The API I'm calling now returns a list of CAs. My test CA was added there and it is returned during the SSL handshake. Now debugging `SecureChannel` shows that my earlier assumptions were correct:

- on first pass the certificate I added is not sent up
- however after getting the CAs list from the server it's inspected for one matching my certificate's issuer and a match is indeed found!
- follwing this successful match `SecureChannel` sets its `m_SelectedClientCertificate` successfully to my certificate but...
- ...unfortunately it STILL doesn't get sent to the server with the next step of the protocol :(

Once the `SecureChannel.m_SelectedClientCertificate` is set, it doesn't seem to be used from `SecureChannel` itself anymore but it is exposed:

```
internal X509Certificate LocalClientCertificate {
            get {
                return m_SelectedClientCertificate;
            }
        }
```

Unfortunately this property is never called in my case :(

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem: my certificate was signed with SHA1. Resigned with SHA256 and behold, it gets sent!